# How to rearrange dependent dropdowns in power apps

Tags: powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

How to rearrange dependent dropdowns in power apps?

I have tried to rearrange through the fields option. I could not find any formula to align the dependent dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have two dropdown 1. State 2. City. So here first you have to disable the City dropdown unless City is not selected or State dropdown's ITEM is not empty.

And it will be enabled unless the User has not change/select a state from the State dropdown.
Then on the State dropdown's OnChange event, you have to collect a ITEMS  ex. Collect(cityItem, Filter (city, sate = State.SelectedText.Value)).

Finally keep this collection cityItem (you got from OnChange event from State dropdown) as the ITEM for City's dropdown.